# React.js: How to update API call from form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Making a weather app and I'm trying to update my api call on submit from a form. This is my first shot at making my own program and I've hit a block. I'm setting my API call from useState, and the idea is the user types in the city, hits the button, and the API call runs again and displays the new data from the city. I'm new to thinking as a programmer so I'm almost certain I'm missing something very simple.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
// import classes from './wCard.css';
// import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


function WCard () {
        const [city,setCity] = useState('Queens');
        // const key = 'APP_KEY';
        const [feels_like,setFeelsLike] = useState('');
        const [mainTemp,setMainTemp] = useState('');
        const [description,setDescription] = useState('');
        const [main,setMain] = useState('');
        const [iconID,setIconID] = useState('');
        
        // useEffect(() => {
            


        const handleChange = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            setCity(event.target.value)
        }

        const handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            setCity(document.getElementsByName("city")[0].value)
            fetch(
                'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + (city) + '&appid&units=imperial'
            )
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    setFeelsLike(data.main.feels_like);
                    setMainTemp(data.main.temp);
                    setDescription(data.weather[0].description);
                    setMain(data.weather[0].main);
                    setIconID(data.weather[0].icon);
                })
        },[city])
        
        
       
    return (
        <Aux>
            <div>
                <label>City</label>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ayyy" onChange={handleChange} />
                    <button type="submit">Weather time</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        <div style={{ display:'flex', justifyContent:'center', padding:'5em' }} >
            <Card style={{ width: '24rem', marginTop: '-3em' }}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={"http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + iconID + "@2x.png"} />
                <h1 style={{ textAlign:'center', color:'#00BFFF' }} >{city}</h1>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{mainTemp}°, feels like {feels_like}°</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text style={{ textTransform:'capitalize' }} >
                    {description}
                    </Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            </div>
        </Aux>
    )    
}

export default WCard;
```

Comment: Try matching the expected value of the state when you first initialise it on creation, for example, if `mainTemp` you expect to be a number then `const [mainTemp,setMainTemp] = useState(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your useEffect isn't being called again, since you passed in a [] as your array of dependencies. Try doing `useEffect(..., [city])`. That way, useEffect will be called on update of `city`

Comment: I think that worked but now a new issue: I get thrown an error as I start typing in the form. I believe it's because it updates the api call immediately so on my first keystroke I get an error. Any idea how I could wait til I hit the button to update?

Comment: Are you still using that `handleChange` function? I don't see it in the code, but I see that you declare it. That's probably what's catching every keystroke- just delete that?

Comment: Yeah I'm not actually using it at all. I have something new though: on submit I am now making another API call but it is being shown as 'undefined'. I must be messing up my handle submit somehow.

Comment: Could you copy and paste what you have now?

Comment: Not in these comments, but I'm almost certain this has something to do with the <input> and my handleSubmit, I'm not targeting the input correctly

Comment: Could you try putting the handleSubmit on... `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` and then change the button to be a `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: Sadly still showing undefined, here's the error message: wCard.js:17 GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=undefined&appid=88223d5e7311d1f2dd7274116e77993d&units=imperial 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Could you move the contents of useEffect (so, that fetch function) into the the handleSubmit. That way, it's only run when you handle submit.

Next, could you make your input text box a controlled component. so, everytime you change it, it updates the value of city. That would be something like `<input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={city}` /> (and bring back the handleChange function you have above)

Comment: To use useEffect inside handleSubmit it has to be a custom hook, so now I'm trying to make that work. It seems like I have to return something from it, but I'm not sure at all about it. Scanning the docs now.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you remove useEffect all together and move the *contents* into that handleSubmit function :)

Comment: Ok super duper weird, but when I first made that change it worked for a bit then crashed. Now I'm getting a weird parsing error, I must be formatting it wrong somehow: Line 41:13:  Parsing error: Identifier 'city' has already been declared, I must be adding the dependency wrong but I'm not sure how

Comment: I made an edit to show the current state of the app, please look when you can!

Comment: Hi there- I directly edited your code above and submitted a request for an edit. What I did was 1. I removed [city] from the handleSubmit function. You don't need that anymore if you're using fetch directly and not using useEffect, and 2. I removed your setCity function in the handleSubmit. When handleSubmit is called, fetch is already using the latest 'city' (because everytime you type it's updating city through the handleChange function). Hopefully this works! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            setCity(event.target.value.city)
            
        }
```

There is a typo. It should be event.target.value not event.target.value.city

And there is no need to have the onChange method.

And as you now know from what Victor said, useEffect will get called if the given dependency changes.

Comment: Yeah got rid of the onChange handler, but even with that change the console is saying:wCard.js:17 GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=undefined&appid=88223d5e7311d1f2dd7274116e77993d&units=imperial 400 (Bad Request), so it's still showing the part i pass in from the state as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

use this on useEffect

```
useEffect(..., [city])
```

and in handleSubmit  there is the problem that event.target is where the click has been triggered, so in this case, the button, you must target the input

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setCity(document.getElementsByName("city")[0].value)
    }
```

the rest of the code is ok

Comment: Did that and the console is showing that city is being plugged into the api call as 'undefined'.

Comment: that is related to the reading, of event.target.value

Comment: Yeah exactly, no idea why though

Comment: take a look at the edit and let me know if it works and if you understand the issue

Comment: in the answer itself, I changed the handleSubmit